# Using the Spectral decomposition to show $K = -i \log (U)$ is normal.

Tags: linear-algebra

> > Let $U$ be a unitary matrix.

Show that $K = -i \log (U)$ is Hermitian. The spectral decomposition states that any diagonalisable matrix is normal so it suffices to show that K is diagonalisable.

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you required to use spectral decomposition?  The proof is trivial by Taylor expansion. Take $U=e^{iX}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(iX)^k}{k!}$.  Term by term Hermitian conjugation gives $U^\ast=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-iX^\ast)^k}{k!} = e^{-iX^\ast}$.  Since $U$ is unitary by assumption, $UU^\ast=I=e^{iX}e^{-iX^\ast}$, and $X=X^\ast$, showing $X$ must be Hermitian.

It follows directly that $K$ is Hermitian by $K=-i \, \log(U)=-i(iX)=X$.

**Edit:** Since spectral decomposition is necessary, any unitary matrix can be diagonalized such that $U = S \, \text{diag}(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_N) S^\ast$, with $\lambda_n=e^{i\phi_n}$, where $S$ is unitary and $\phi_n \in \mathbb{R}$.  This leads to $$\log(U)=S \, \log[\text{diag}(e^{i\phi_1},...,e^{i\phi_N})] S^\ast,$$
multiplying the diagonal matrix by $-i$ gives $K$ directly in eigendecomposed form as
$$K = S \, \text{diag}(\phi_1,...,\phi_N) S^\ast,$$
which is Hermitian since $S$ is unitary and the diagonal matrix is real.

Comment: Yes, it is necessary.

Comment: Edited to add a path that makes use of spectral decomposition.

Comment: What is $\log$ for you ? In particular, how do you define $\log(-1)$ ?

Comment: I interpreted log in the question to be natural log (base $e$), so $\log(-1)=i \pi$.  That's the standard base in the context of Lie groups.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\log(UU^*) = \log(U) + \log(U)^*$

Comment: This is still crytic. Can you illuminate further?